# Recommendation for a simple x86 emulator and operating system

Tags: operating-system, x86, emulation, i386, emscripten

As a personal learning project, I want to port an existing x86 emulator library to JavaScript and then run a very simple operating system on top of it.

My only requirement for the library is that it should be written in C\C++, as I want to use emscripten and asm.js to compile the source files to JavaScript. The library should at least be able to interpret x86 opcodes; the specific environment details for JavaScript (memory, GUI, interrupts etc.) I can implement myself. The operating system doesn't have any requirement, as long as it is simple enough and can run on the emulator.

So far in my research, [Softx86](http://softx86.sourceforge.net/) seems like the most viable solution, as it seems simple enough to port to JavaScript (it only does CPU emulation). The simplest 16 bit real-mode operating system I can find is [MikeOS](http://mikeos.berlios.de/), the only problem being that it requires a 386 processor, which Softx86 cannot emulate and I am not sure if they are completely compatible.

My question is if anyone knows an alternate combination of emulator-OS that is simple enough to be ported to JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who will come across this thread in the future, I've decided to port [Fake86](http://fake86.rubbermallet.org/) to JavaScript, and use MS-DOS as the operating system.

You can see a **live demo** [here](http://colin-dumitru.github.io/fake86JS/)

It runs very, very slowly, and currently only runs on Firefox, but it works nonetheless.

You can see the full source code [here](https://github.com/colin-dumitru/fake86JS)